# Proving formula of a recursive sequence using strong induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, induction

Question:

A sequence is defined recursively by $ a_1 = 1, a_2 = 4, a_3 = 9$ and $ a_n = a_{n-1} - a_{n-2} + a_{n-3} + 2(2n-3)$ for $ n \ge 4$. Prove that $ a_n = n^{2}$ for all $ n \ge 1$.

My attempt:

**Proof by strong induction:**

Base Case: $ n =1, a_1 = (1)^{2} = 1 \ ,$
           $ n = 2, a_2 = (2)^{2} = 4 \,$
           $ n = 3, a_3= (3)^{2} = 9. \ $
So Base Case holds.

I.H: Assume the result is true for $ n = 1, 2, ....., k \ge 3$

Want to prove $\  a_{k+1} = (k+1)^{2}$.

$\begin{align}
a_{k+1} &= a_k - a_{k-1} + a_{k-2} + 2(2(k+1) -3)\text{, by recurrence relation}
\\& = k^{2} - (k-1)^{2} + (k-2)^{2} + 4k-2\text{, by I.H}
\\& = k^{2} - k^{2} + 2k -1 + k^{2} -4k + 4+4k -2
\\& = k^{2} + 2k + 1
\\& = (k+1)^{2}
\end{align}$

Hence, by strong induction, the result holds for all natural numbers.

Is this the correct way to prove a formula for a recursive sequence using strong induction?

Comment: Just as a note, you can auto align things using the `align` mode.  Separate lines with `\\ ` and set tabs with `&`.

Comment: You seem to be missing a term in the definition of the recurrence relation.

Comment: Sorry I missed a term. I have updated the question

Comment: Ok, everythin looks good!

Comment: So the reason we use strong induction instead of normal induction is because we need an assumption for $ k$, $ k-1$ and $ k-2$  right?

Comment: @JoshMitkitzel Exactly. THough some would consider this weak induction, but with an expanded (though fixed size) base.

Comment: If I was given the first two terms of the sequence then I would only have two base cases right?

Comment: @JoshMitkitzel Well, the recurrence relation will tell you how many base cases you should have. But that will most likely coincide with the number of first terms given, sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did well, and the proof is all good!

As far as your follow-up questions go:

The recurrence relation should tell you how many bases cases you need. In particular, look at the term that goes 'furthest back'. E.g. If you have a recurrence relation

$$a_n= 2a_{n-4}+6a_{n-2}$$

Then you will need $4$ base cases, since you go $4$ back.